# Cannot use Cupertino timepicker by int time

Tags: flutter, timepicker

I cannot use timepicker

If i change time to digits such as 10 and 30 ...
I define time as int but cannot run

Could you give me your advise?

Thanks

```
  @override   void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: time),
    );   }
```

this is whole code
https://github.com/Postboll/workout_mgmt/tree/graph/lib

Comment: What does the posted code have to do with a timepicker? Please post a [mcve] including the expected beheviour and what you observe instead.

Comment: This is perfectly fine and should work if you replace any int with time. Provide minimal code